# Call each method in a list in a loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here's what I'd like to do, but not sure if there's a way to do this:

```
methods = [__add__, __sub__, __mul__]

a = 3
b = 4

for m in methods:
    print a.m(b)
```

The result should be:

```
7
-1
12
```

How would I accomplish this for any sized list, and what is this called in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do exactly what you're trying to do there, you need to use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
methods = ['__add__', '__sub__', '__mul__']

a = 3
b = 4

for m in methods:
    print getattr(a, m)(b)
```

However, for this particular example at least, it's better to do this:

```
from operator import add, mul, sub

ops = [add, sub, mul]

a = 3
b = 4

for op in ops:
    print op(a, b)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) to invoke methods by their names:

```
methods = ['__add__', '__sub__', '__mul__']

a = 3
b = 4

for m in methods:
    print getattr(a, m)(b)
```